# UICollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths

Tags: xcode, pagination, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I've been trying to wrap my head around the reloadItemsAtIndexPaths method of UICollectionView.

I have an array of objects called objectsArray.   When a user scrolls to the bottom of my collection view, I fetch the next batch of objects from the backend and append it to objectsArray by calling [objectsArray addObjectsFromArray:objects];   After doing so, I call [self.collectionView reloadData] which I know is expensive.

I'd like to optimize with the code below but I get an assertion failure when calling reloadItemsAtIndexPaths.

```
    if (self.searchPage == 0) {
        parseObjectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:relevantDeals];
        [self.collectionView reloadData];

    } else {

        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (int i = 0; i < [relevantDeals count]; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0];
            [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        }

        [parseObjectsArray addObjectsFromArray:relevantDeals];
        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
        //[self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
```

Error:
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.2/UICollectionView.m:3716

Any help/tips is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the items being added are new, in other words you are adding items which weren't there before.  In that case, just replace reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths with insertItemsAtIndexPaths:

```
[self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths]; // Use this for newly added rows
//[self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths]; // Use this for existing rows which have changed
```

Comment: I've tried the insertItemsAtIndexPaths method as well and end up with the same assertion above.   Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 4):

The assertion error was misleading.   It wasn't until after I implemented

```
            @try
            {
                [self.collectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
            }
            @catch (NSException *except)
            {
                NSLog(@"DEBUG: failure to insertItemsAtIndexPaths.  %@", except.description);
            }
```

Did I realize was calculating my indexPaths wrong.   My index offset for the new objects was off by one making my collectionview think I was adding more objects than I specified in numberOfItemsInSection.

Thanks for all those who attempted to help!

Answer (score 0):

This error often arises when you increase/decrease the number of items in the array but it doesn't match the data source method

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

Are you updating it appropriately?

Comment: - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [parseObjectsArray count];
}   It looks like it gets called right before the assertion because I NSLogged the value of [parseObjectsArray count] and it returns the higher value with new objects added to the array.   Thanks for the suggestion though!